# Can we use dynatrace with protractor e2e tests?

Tags: selenium, protractor, functional-testing, e2e-testing, dynatrace

We have successfully set up a selenium grid using docker. Now we are trying to have dynatrace all the performance metrics for the functional UI tests, but I am having a very tough time trying to get dynatrace connected through the docker.yml file.

According to the instructions provided by the dynatrace community this is what I have set up:

> https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT62/Browser+Agent+Configuration

I have the following environment variables set up in the docker.yml file as follows:

```
    - DT_AGENTACTIVE=true
    - DT_AGENTNAME=name-of-agent
    - DT_SERVER=host:port
```

Also in my protractor config file this is what i have for firefox and chrome:

```
    {
        browserName: 'firefox',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 10,
        firefoxOptions: {
            args: ['--lang=en',
                '--window-size=1024,3000']
        }
    },
    //max-desktop-chrome - default screen size
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 10,
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--lang=en',
                '--window-size=1024,3000', '--disable-extensions']
        }
    }
```

I still do not see that dynatrace agent in the dynatrace client. Any ideas what I can be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not using the Browser Agent (as this will be deprecated) but instead use our new UEM-based Test Automation Integration using our JavaScript Agent approach. With that the only thing you need to do is to instrument your app-servers and enable UEM. This will then load our JavaScript agent into your page. You can modify your Selenium Scripts to pass the Test Name to our JavaScript agent. Once that is done you will automatically see all tests captured in dynatrace with all WPO metrics showing up per test and build
Here are some links you should check out

- https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT65/UI-Driven+Browser+Test
- https://github.com/Dynatrace/Dynatrace-Test-Automation-Samples/tree/master/selenium

  - https://github.com/Dynatrace/Dynatrace-Test-Automation-Samples/tree/master/saucelabs

I also have some youtube tutorials where we show this capability: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6

Andi